# PHP error suppression on static class function call

Tags: php

I've got this call to Pear Mailer that gives me warnings not to be called statically but it works and I'm fully aware of that warning. Can I suppress it with an `@` as I need other warnings?

`$mail_smtp_public =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_params_public);`

These, obviously, do not work:

`$mail_smtp_public =& @Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_params_public);`
`$mail_smtp_public =& Mail::@factory("smtp", $smtp_params_public);`

Comment: Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Ok, removing the reference operator works fine, interesting...

Comment: @user583576 There's no explanation as to why it doesn't work when assigning by reference.

Comment: block all errors using error_reporting(0) the error you can find it in may apache logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
@$mail_smtp_public =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_params_public);
```

or

```
try {
    $mail_smtp_public =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_params_public);
    if ($mail_smtp_public) {
        throw new Exception('Your other message');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Nice! The first option works! The second option would probably be an overkill for what I was doing. Thanks.